# Hide text with asterisks

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to hide a type of string data that the user types and then by means of a data bing in agular I show it in another component and what I want is to mask/hide part of this data with asterisks. How can I do it? I am not very expert in js, is it possible to do it with css?

```
            <p class="subtitle">
                Hemos enviado un correo electrónico a<br />
                <b>{{ capturedEmail }}</b> con las instrucciones<br />
                para la recuperación de tu contraseña.<br />
                Una vez reestablezcas la contraseña, podrás<br />
                ingresar a la plataforma con tus datos.
            </p>
```

In the code snippet above, the {{ capturedEmail }} is who I want to add that property

Example:

correo@mail.com -> C***@mail.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an Angular Pipe for it.
Attached herewith is a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-pipe-asterisk-vsr9yh?file=src/app/app.component.html)** for your reference

```
<h1>{{ capturedEmail | emailAsterisk }}</h1>
```

```
@Pipe({ name: 'emailAsterisk' })
export class EmailAsteriskPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {
    return value 
      ? value.replace(/\B.+@/g, (c, ) => c.split('').slice(0, -1).map(v => '*').join('') + '@') 
      : value;
  }

}
```

**Result**

```
correo@mail.com         >    c*****@mail.com
john.wick22@gmail.com   >    j**********@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you try to mask the email with asteriks, so pass any email to following this will solve your problem.

Try this below javascript code!

```js
const capturedEmail = function (emailAddress, callback) {
    function mask(str) {
        var strLen = str.length;
        if (strLen > 4) {
            return str.substr(0, 1) + str.substr(1, strLen - 1).replace(/\w/g, '*') + str.substr(-1,1);
        } 
        return str.replace(/\w/g, '*');
    }
    return emailAddress.replace(/([\w.]+)@([\w.]+)(\.[\w.]+)/g, function (m, p1, p2, p3) {      
        return callback(null,mask(p1) + '@' + p2 + p3);
    });
     
}
 
capturedEmail('random string username@example.com test', function(err,res){
console.log(res);
});
```

```
Result: u*******e@example.com
```